# Reaproveitando string no XML

Tags: android, xml

Ex.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="primeiro_nome">Bigown</string>
   <string name="nome_completo">{primeiro nome} Silva</string>
</resources>
```

Tem como reaproveitar a string primeiro_nome na string abaixo direto no xml?

Answer (score 1):

> Apenas como observação eu não testei isto diretamente com o SDK do Android, mas uso com o Xamarin e está funcionando perfeitamente para mim

Você pode declarar novas entidades em seu XML para poder reaproveitar textos, ficando mais fácil assim atualizar certos valores que se repetem, eu estou usando da seguinte forma

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY telefone "(12) 3456 7890">
    <!ENTITY site "http://www.meusite.com.br">
]>
<resources>
    <string name="contato">Entre em contato com o nosso suporte pelo telefone &telefone;</string>
    <string name="saibamais">Conheça mais sobre o nosso produto visitando no website &site;.</string>
</resources>
```

Repare que no XML eu declarei uma entidade chamada `telefone`, e ela é usada como `&telefone;` no XML

Comment: Testei aqui no SDK do Android e aparentemente funcionou como o esperado, boa técnica vou passar a utiliza-la. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Para copiar o valor de um elemento em outro você precisa utilizar XSLT e usar a declaração <`xsl:copy-of select="$NOME_DO_ELEMENTO_COPIADO" />`.

O exemplo que você passou ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<resources> 
    <string name="primeiro_nome">Bigown</string> 
    <string name="nome_completo"><xsl:copy-of select="$primeiro_nome" /> Silva</string> 
</resources>
```

A documentação completa para referência está na página http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp

Comment: não consegui, estou utilizando no xml para android :/

Comment: @Josinaldo Não havíamos declarado o namespace **xsl:stylesheet** no cabeçalho do arquivo, e por isso o xsl:copy-of não estava sendo reconhecido. Editei minha resposta adicionando esse namespace. Pode ser que agora funcione. Se ainda assim não funcionar, ainda temos a opção de declarar essas definições de transformação do XML em um arquivo externo e referenciá-lo em seu arquivo de recursos.